# How to convert a search string coldfusion-loop into a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, loops, coldfusion

I inherited a coldfusion8 site, which is using some search functionality.

I'm trying to store standardized database querys into stored procedures. Since I'm a newbie on both Coldfusion and MySQL I'm now wondering whether I can do this in MySQL:

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="find_cats">
    SELECT wg.no, wg.type, wg.keywords, wg.lang
    FROM cats AS wg 
    <cfloop list="searchForm.cats_search_string" delimiters=", " item="tag">
      WHERE wg.keywords LIKE <cfqueryparam value='%#tag#%' cfsqltype='cf_sql_varchar'> AND
    </cfloop>
    wg.lang = <cfqueryparam value="#Session.lang#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
</cfquery>
<cfset cond_cats = "AND (1=2">
    <cfoutput query="find_cats">
        <!--- check if found category belongs to either AAA or BBB classifcation --->
        <cfif wg.type is "AAA">
            <cfset cond_cats = cond_cats & " OR categoryID1 = #wg.no#">
        </cfif>
        <cfif wg.typ is "BBB">
            <cfset cond_cats = cond_cats & " OR categoryID2 = #wg.no#">
        </cfif>
    </cfoutput>
    <cfset cond_cats = cond_cats & ")">
```

The search can either be keyword or index (AAA, BBB) based. I'm still trying to understand what is happending, but so far I think if the user enters a string like:

```
 string1, string2, string3 string4
```

The first part loops through the four strings (delimiter comma and space) and querys the database for matching keywords. It then creates a new **cond_cats** variable, which is used when the actual search takes place. I guess it replaces the search strings, with matching categories, but I'm not sure here, as the result will be

```
AND (1=2 OR category1 = 12345 OR category2 = 88888 )
```

Which is appended to the actual search query.

**My questions:**
Is there a way in MySQL to split the user-entered search string, so I'm able to run the loop? The second part should be an out-parameter of the stored procedure, shouldn't it? If this is run before every search, should it be a stored procedure at all or should I keep using a database query?

Thanks for some input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you described, I am not seeing much benefit to wrapping it in a stored procedure/function. Databases are not really optimized for string manipulation. While looping is possible, the equivalent sql code is usually far less elegant. Plus it may require the use of dynamic sql (or a temp table to do it safely).

However, looking over your code I believe you could eliminate the second `cfloop`altogether by using a single [`IN (....)`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) clause instead of constructing a series `OR` conditions. (The two are equivalent.)

Just modify the first query to retrieve *only* categories for the desired types ie "AAA" and "BBB".

```
<cfquery datasource="db" name="find_cats">
    SELECT  wg.no
    FROM    cats AS wg 
    WHERE   wg.lang = <cfqueryparam value="#Session.lang#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
    AND     wg.type IN ('AAA', 'BBB')
    AND  ( 1 = 2
         <cfloop list="#searchForm.cats_search_string#" delimiters=", " item="tag">
              OR wg.keywords LIKE <cfqueryparam value='%#tag#%' cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar"> 
          </cfloop>
       )
</cfquery>
```

Then use [ValueList](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6d19.html) to feed the results into your second query. It is possible you may even be able to merge your two queries into one. But that all depends on the complexity of your search query.

```
WHERE categoryID1 IN 
( 
    <cfqueryparam value="#valueList(find_cats.no)#" list="true" ... > 
)
```

---

**EDIT:**  I think you could still use valueList. Just add a `CASE` statement to the first query that separates the matching values into two columns:

```
SELECT  wg.no
        , CASE WHEN wg.type = 'AAA' THEN wg.no ELSE NULL END AS ID1Values
        , CASE WHEN wg.type = 'BBB' THEN wg.no ELSE NULL END AS ID2Values
...
```

Then generate a list of the values in each column:

```
     <cfset firstList  = valueList(find_cats.ID1Values)>
     <cfset secondList = valueList(find_cats.ID2Values)>
```

Finally use those lists within your search query.

```
   WHERE 1 = 2

   <cfif listLen(firstList)>
         OR categoryID1 IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#firstList#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> )
   </cfif>

   <cfif listLen(secondList)>
         OR categoryID2 IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#secondList#" list="true" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> )
   </cfif>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Not sure if it helps, but I valueList may be useful.

Comment: Well it sounded like your question was "would this be better as a stored procedure?" IMO no. So the code above demonstrates how to write the cfquery more efficiently *and safely* (without all the concatenation ie dynamic sql) But feel free to leave the question open for a while to get other opinions.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear. Question is answered correctly. My sample code was had an error, so your snippet works for the faulty sample code. Problem is categoryID1 should be categoryID1 and cateogryID2. ID1 is the name for a product classification for sporting goods, ID2 for apparel. So I need to check if any of the keywords match any category in both indices and return the category number in each index (if there is one). My example only polled ID1, so IN would work. I haven't found a way to use it with two separate IDs. I have edited my question. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: I think it is still possible with valueList. See my updated response.

Comment: do I need to include a delimiter with valueList for MySql?

Comment: No. It defaults to a comma ",". You only need to specify it if you want to use a *different* delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try "Full text" index in mysql.

Comment: Not really my question... I do have a full-text search, but in addition there are finer grained search criteria like the above. I'm trying to make this a stored proc, so any help on this would be highly appreciated. Thx!